# Batch Class Add contact to Account

Tags: batch-processing, apex

I have created 20 records with the 'name=SampleAccountOne'.  I am trying to create a batch class that will add a given contact to the 20 records.  Stuck with syntax and where to go.  Any help in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

```
global class UpdateProjectNameBatch implementsDatabase.Batchable<sObject> {
  List<Contact> conList = new conList<Contact>();
  String query = 'Select Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Name = \'SampleAccountOne\''

  global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
  }

  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc,List<sObject> batch){
    for(Contact c : conList){
        batch.c = 'New Contact Name';
    }
  }

  global void finish(){

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to associate a single contact to multiple accounts. This functionality was released in [Spring 16'](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_sales_shared_contacts.htm) and is implemented through a Salesforce Junction object - AccountContactRelation.

I assume you have already enabled this functionality through the UI and a parent Account is declared for this Contact.

I have modified your code to associate the contact to all 20 account.

```
    global class UpdateProjectNameBatch implements Database.Batchable 
    <sObject> 
     {  ID conId = '0037F00000IfCCKQA3';    //Add the contact Id here
  List<AccountContactRelation> ListInsertion = new List<AccountContactRelation>();
  String query = 'Select Id,Name FROM Account WHERE Name = \'SampleAccountOne\'';

  global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc)
  {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
  }

  global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc,List<Account> batch){

      for (Account a : batch)
      {
          AccountContactRelation   c =  new AccountContactRelation();

          c.AccountId = a.id;
          c.contactId = conId;
          ListInsertion.add(c);
      }


     Insert ListInsertion;

  }

  global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
  {
    //DoNothing.
  }
}
```